# Error Wildfly jdbc : The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc, wildfly

I use an old version of Server Express (MS SQL Server 2005 - 9.X) because of legacies issues, therefor I cannot use TLS2 nor TLS. (I know, it's not recommended).

With R dbi and java alone, the JDBC connection works with this line :

```java
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves");
```

For other application that we have (R Shiny, Flask),  we've done this replacement in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and it works.

that

```
  [ssl_sect]
  system_default = system_default_sect
  [system_default_sect]
  CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
```

replaced by

```
   ...
   openssl_conf = default_conf
   ...
  [default_conf]
  ssl_conf = ssl_sect

  [ssl_sect]
  system_default = system_default_sect
  
  [system_default_sect]
  # MinProtocol = TLSv1.1
  CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0
```

Like I've read on Stackoverflow, I've writen these line in java without Wildfly and it works, i.e. the connection and `SELECT` get lines without exception:

- at the call of java `java -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false -cp '.:jar_libraries/mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar'`
- and in the code below `Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms",...)`

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // allows you to define the forbidden encryption algorithms. I removed everything that concerned SSLv3 and TLSv1.0 and 1.1 so that it would be authorized by java.
        Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves");

        /* Connection to the database */
        Connection bdd = null;
        try {
            if (bdd == null || bdd.isClosed()) {
                try { Class.forName(Constantes.BDD_DRIVER); }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                try { bdd = DriverManager.getConnection(Constantes.BDD_URL, Constantes.BDD_LOGIN, Constantes.BDD_MDP); System.out.println("Connexion succes !"); } 
                catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();  System.out.println("\nConnexion failed ! : "+e.getMessage()); }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); System.out.println("Error closing database"); }

        Main.query(bdd);
    }

    private static void query(Connection bdd)
    {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        /* Query execution */
        try {
            stmt = bdd.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constantes.TABLE_TICKETS + ";");
            //rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 99 as toto;");
        } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        /* Processing the query result */
        try {
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(Constantes.TICKETS_ID));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(Constantes.TICKETS_ETAT));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

but with Wildfly that throws this exception :

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server with Secure Sockets Layer encryption (SSL). Error: « "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12] ». ClientConnectionId:3b679cc4-868a-4389-b913-424d775c72c3

I launch my Wildfly server with this line :

```bash
./standalone.sh -b=MY.IP -DruntimeEnvironment=dev -DpathServerConfig=....../main/resources/serveur.config.xml
```

`-DruntimeEnvironment` and `-DpathServerConfig` are the my custom parameters to use the correct constants to connecting my database

This issue occurs under Windows and Linux.

Like in pure java, I would like to not throw exception in Wildfly java and get my datas from my legacy RDBMS.

**EDIT :**
It works, I changed the values ​​of the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` properties in the `/etc/java-<version>-openjdk/security/java.security` file like this.

```
# Example:
#   jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048, \
#       rsa_pkcs1_sha1, secp224r1
#
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```

**But I'm still wait for a better proposition because I don't like writing in java files**

Comment: I am surprised we don't get any questions about SQL 2000. On a serious note: what are the legacy issues that are preventing you from upgrading?

Comment: it's a company that uses old software that forces them to stay on this version

Comment: they are using a 32 bit application

Comment: SQL Express is a stand alone SQL Server instance. Database server bitness should not affect applications. In any case SQL Server 2014 Express has a 32-bit version (https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=42299) and supports TLS 1.3